# is it poosible to deploy angular2 application on wildfly9 or above without using hashing for routing?

Tags: angular, wildfly-9

I have one angular2 app, I can deploy it on wildfly9 and it works fine when i use hashing.

If I remove hashing its not routing properly(actually displaying 404 not found resource) though it can load the index.html. So is there any suggestion how can I deploy angular2 app without hashing on Wildfly9?

Comment: Add a servlet filter to your webapp that forwards to index.html for all GET requests other than the ones to static assets or REST API URLs.

Comment: how that would help?

Comment: It would help by solving your problem. Any request from the browser to your app would go through the filter, which would send back the index.html page. The angular application would start, inspect the path of the URL, and go to the corresponding route. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: Is it possible to deploy the dist(I mean the static content) of the angular2 on  apache2 without hashing??